# Error recording macro to create Pivot Grid

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-grid

I'm seeing this error: Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qs9zk.png).

I've looked over several post but can't figure it out.

The error is on this line when creating the ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(). Seems like it is on the SourceData part.

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "FoodSales!R1C1:R1048576C9", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="Sheet16!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable8", DefaultVersion:=7
    Sheets("Sheet16").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8")
        .ColumnGrand = True
```

I'm trying to make the following pivot table:

Row - City
Column - Product
Data - Total Price

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the full code:

```
Sub Macro10()
'
' Macro10 Macro
'

'
    Columns("A:I").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "FoodSales!R1C1:R1048576C9", Version:=7).CreatePivotTable TableDestination _
        :="Sheet16!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable8", DefaultVersion:=7
    Sheets("Sheet16").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("City")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotFields("Product")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable8").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable8").PivotFields("TotalPrice"), "Sum of TotalPrice", xlSum
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I fixed it:

Instead of taking the results from recording the macro, I found this [article](https://excelchamps.com/blog/vba-to-create-pivot-table/) and was able to update the top portion where the `PivotCaches.Create()` is created to make it more dynamic I guess.

I can add this code to the top and then the rest of the recorded macro works perfect!

Update problem area code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTableMain").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTableMain"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTableMain")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("FoodSales")
    
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTableBraves")
```

Here is the full result:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B
'
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("PivotTableMain").Delete
Sheets.Add Before:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = "PivotTableMain"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTableMain")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("FoodSales")
    
LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)
    
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 2), _
TableName:="PivotTableBraves")

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableBraves")
        .ColumnGrand = True
        .HasAutoFormat = True
        .DisplayErrorString = False
        .DisplayNullString = True
        .EnableDrilldown = True
        .ErrorString = ""
        .MergeLabels = False
        .NullString = ""
        .PageFieldOrder = 2
        .PageFieldWrapCount = 0
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RowGrand = True
        .SaveData = True
        .PrintTitles = False
        .RepeatItemsOnEachPrintedPage = True
        .TotalsAnnotation = False
        .CompactRowIndent = 1
        .InGridDropZones = False
        .DisplayFieldCaptions = True
        .DisplayMemberPropertyTooltips = False
        .DisplayContextTooltips = True
        .ShowDrillIndicators = True
        .PrintDrillIndicators = False
        .AllowMultipleFilters = False
        .SortUsingCustomLists = True
        .FieldListSortAscending = False
        .ShowValuesRow = False
        .CalculatedMembersInFilters = False
        .RowAxisLayout xlCompactRow
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableBraves").PivotCache
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsDefault
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableBraves").RepeatAllLabels xlRepeatLabels
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableBraves").PivotFields("Category")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableBraves").PivotFields("City")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTableBraves").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTableBraves").PivotFields("TotalPrice"), "Sum of TotalPrice", xlSum
    Range("H19").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Range("B5:G10").Select
    Selection.Style = "Currency"
    Range("E8").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```